# (Casting) errors using extract_(relevant_)features from tsfresh

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, casting

Trying out Python package tsfresh I run into issues in the first steps. Given a series how to (automatically) make features for it? This snippet produces different errors based on which part I try.

```
import tsfresh
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#tfX, tfy = tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions.make_forecasting_frame(pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000)/50), kind='float64', max_timeshift=50, rolling_direction=1)
#rf = tsfresh.extract_relevant_features(tfX, y=tfy, n_jobs=1, column_id='id')
tfX, tfy = tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions.make_forecasting_frame(pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000)/50), kind=1, max_timeshift=50, rolling_direction=1)
rf = tsfresh.extract_relevant_features(tfX, y=tfy, n_jobs=1, column_id='id')
```

The errors are in the first case

> """ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line
>   119, in worker
>           result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\utilities\distribution.py",
>   line 38, in _function_with_partly_reduce
>           results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\utilities\distribution.py",
>   line 37, in 
>           results = (map_function(chunk, **kwargs) for chunk in chunk_list)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py",
>   line 358, in _do_extraction_on_chunk
>           return list(_f())   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py",
>   line 350, in _f
>           result = [("", func(data))]   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\feature_calculators.py",
>   line 193, in variance_larger_than_standard_deviation
>           y = np.var(x)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py",
>   line 3157, in var
>           **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py",
>   line 110, in _var
>           arrmean, rcount, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe', subok=False) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' """

and in the second case

> """ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line
>   119, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\utilities\distribution.py",
>   line 38, in _function_with_partly_reduce
>       results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\utilities\distribution.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       results = (map_function(chunk, **kwargs) for chunk in chunk_list)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py",
>   line 358, in _do_extraction_on_chunk
>       return list(_f())   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py",
>   line 345, in _f
>       result = func(data, param=parameter_list)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\feature_calculators.py",
>   line 1752, in friedrich_coefficients
>       coeff = _estimate_friedrich_coefficients(x, m, r)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\feature_calculators.py",
>   line 145, in _estimate_friedrich_coefficients
>       result.dropna(inplace=True)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 4598, in dropna
>       result = self.loc(axis=axis)[mask]   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1500, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1859, in _getitem_axis
>       if is_iterator(key):   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py",
>   line 157, in is_iterator
>       return hasattr(obj, '**next**')   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 5065, in **getattr**
>       if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3984, in _can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name
>       return name in self   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\category.py",
>   line 327, in **contains**
>       return contains(self, key, container=self._engine)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py",
>   line 188, in contains
>       loc = cat.categories.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py",
>   line 770, in get_loc
>       start, stop = self._find_non_overlapping_monotonic_bounds(key)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py",
>   line 717, in _find_non_overlapping_monotonic_bounds
>       start = self._searchsorted_monotonic(key, 'left')   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py",
>   line 681, in _searchsorted_monotonic
>       return sub_idx._searchsorted_monotonic(label, side)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 4755, in _searchsorted_monotonic
>       return self.searchsorted(label, side=side)   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py",
>   line 1501, in searchsorted
>       return self._values.searchsorted(value, side=side, sorter=sorter) TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to
>   dtype('

np.**version**, tsfresh.**version** are ('1.15.4', 'unknown'). I installed tsfresh using conda, probably from conda-forge. I am on Windows 10. Using another kernel with np.**version**, tsfresh.**version** ('1.15.4', '0.11.2') lead to the same results.

Trying the first couple of cells from [timeseries_forecasting_basic_example.ipynb](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/blob/master/notebooks/timeseries_forecasting_basic_example.ipynb) yields the casting error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Either the version on conda(-forge) or one of the dependencies was the issue. So using "conda uninstall tsfresh", "conda install patsy future six tqdm" and "pip install tsfresh" combined did the trick.